# how to make "type effect" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web

this code should type one letter from the string `myText`  every 200 MilliSecond to be like Type Effect, but it's type `undefinded` instead of `letters`.

```js
var myText = "loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlorem",
    myButton = document.getElementById("Button"),
    result = document.getElementById("type"),
    i;
myButton.onclick = function (){
    "use strict";
    setInterval(function(){
        result.textContent += myText[i];
        i++;
    }, 200);
}
```

```html
<p id="type"></p>
    <button  id="Button">Click!</button>
```

Comment: [`i;` -> `i = 0;` on line 4](https://jsbin.com/gogidig/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing i = 0, initial value

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
result.textContent += myText.substring(i, i+1);
```

In JS (short and imprecise explanation), with `myText[1]` you are trying to access the property "1" of the object String(myText).

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap this in a re-usable function and add a check to see how many of the characters have been written.

You can cancel the interval, once you have reached the end of the string.

You can enclose additional parameters inside the interval, by passing them in after the timeout.

```js
const myText = "loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlorem";

document.getElementById('my-button').onclick = (e) => {
  autoType(myText, '#type-1', 50);
  autoType(myText, '#type-2', 100);
}

function autoType(text, target, timeout) {
  target = typeof target === 'string' ?
      document.querySelector(target) : target;
  let intervalId = setInterval((options) => {
    if (options.index >= text.length - 1) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    target.textContent += text[options.index];
    options.index++;
  }, timeout, { index: 0 });
}
```

```html
<p id="type-1"></p>
<p id="type-2"></p>
<button id="my-button">Click!</button>
```